# gdb on top of LLVM?

Tags: c++, c, llvm

Is there any debugger, like gdb or something else, aimed for C/C++, that runs on top of LLVM?

Given how well engineered LLVM is, this almost seems like a perfect opportunity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [llvm-db](http://llvm.org/releases/1.2/docs/SourceLevelDebugging.html).

Comment: I just tried running llvm-db (version 2.6) and I got a message that said: `NOTE: llvm-db is known useless right now.` I guess that project is no longer being maintained?

Answer (score 5):

Recently, the LLDB project was created as a modular tool for adding debugging capabilities to LLVM. At this time it only supports OS X, but it has a C++ api, a standalone executable and Python bindings.

http://lldb.llvm.org/

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean one that allows you to step through llvm ir as if it were a set of assembly instructions? Then no, nothing like that exists. You can pass debug information in through the llvm ir and get it to generate debug information for your target (limited to dwarf at the moment).